# IntelliJ IDEA: how to revoke reformat code / optimize imports dialog?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

So I've pressed `Do not show this dialog in the future` (screenshot taken from the web).

[image: Reformat code dialog]

It's been a while and now I want to change default reformat behavior.

I can't seem to find an option to show this dialog again.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update** 2015/10:

In current versions of IntelliJ (and likely Android studio and other IntelliJ based IDEs) there no longer seems to be this option as it is not needed.

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> no longer shows the dialog, instead it directly reformats the file and gives you a hint that you can display the dialog using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. That dialog no longer includes *Do not show again* option.

[image]

---

For older IntelliJ versions these dialogs can be re-enabled in *Settings/Editor/General*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. There are so much options that I could barely see it.

Comment: @DoctororDrive No problem. Btw Intellij settings section has search dialog. That's how I find most of the options I'm looking for. Just type in "Dialog" and the number of options you have to look through is drastically reduced :)

Comment: I know, thx, btw I used it before asking the question and still managed to miss it.

Comment: I can't find these options anymore in Android Studio 1.2.2.

Comment: This option seems mysteriously absent in 14.1.5

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of IntelliJ or Android studio the dialogs can be found under Settings/Editor in Formatting section

Comment: Where do you see the option for "Show Reformat Code dialog" in Android Studio?