# Open reformat file dialog

Tags: intellij-idea

I enabled remove unused imports and don't show again for reformat dialog window ,now i want to disable remove unused imports , how can i get reformat file dialog back ?

`Shift + Cmd+ Alt + L` throwing following error - `Format Error : Error on formatting spec`

Intellij Version : 14.0.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA: how to revoke reformat code / optimize imports dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747355/intellij-idea-how-to-revoke-reformat-code-optimize-imports-dialog)

Comment: thank you , that indeed solved my issue :)